# Is it safe to pre-check for a potential XSS attack by testing for "<"?

Tags: html, xss

Let's assume we want to write a function that checks input parameters
for a *potential* XSS attack (code is written in Python, but you get the idea):

```py
def is_potential_xss(s):
    assert type(s) is str

    if not "<" in s:
        # pre-check: it cannot be a HTML fragment
        return False
    # ... 
    # do a sophisticated, but slow, parsing of the string to detect
    # malicious tags or attributes.
    ...
```

So here's my question:

Can I safely assume that any html tag must contain a literal `"<"`, e.g.
`<script>` or are there other representations that a browser would
**interpret and execute**?
For example `&#60;script>` would not be executed afaik.

**Edit:** As @tobias-k noted, XSS would be possible with strings that don't contain `<`, when inserted in a special context like a tag attribute. However this question is about html fragments that are rendered as html node.

Comment: For content placed as a nodes text this may likely be enough. But if you have a placeholder in attrs like `<img src="{{USERINPUT}}">` no `<` is necessary for xss.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the heads-up. I was aware of this and will update the question.